# AngularJs Firebase Register and Login Authentication with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I created a function to enable me to login and register. So I have this code:

```
$scope.register = function(username, password) {
        fbAuth.$createUser({email: username, password: password}).then(function(userData) {
            return fbAuth.$authWithPassword({
                email: username,
                password: password
            });
        }).then(function(authData) {
            $state.go("secure");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("ERROR: " + error);
        });
    }
})
```

Then I have this in my index.hmtl

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>


    <!-- compiled css output -->
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
      <!-- Firebase -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <!-- AngularFire -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.2/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
```

When I emulate/launch my code I have this error on my error console:

```
ERROR: Error: Firebase.createUser failed: First argument must contain the key "email" with type "string"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks correct at first glance, so likely something else is going wrong. Can you set up a reproduction of the problem on a site like jsfiddle or jsbin, so that I can have a look?

Comment: As you can see everything is straight up and I dont know how to set up cordova codes on jsfiddle

Comment: Could you try this with the latest version of the Firebase SDK (2.2.9)?